# What are the multiple output files from Cython for?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cython, cythonize

I am on Python 2.7 and new to Cython.

Background:

I have 20+ py files in my project and then I found the slowness are coming from 3 of them.

So I use Cython for those files, they are now compiled with Cython and become pyd files without any issue. (I spent days to investigate the problem, look for the best solution, improve the way coding in Python but I still have to use Cython for performance reason)

Except the pyd file, under the build folder, there are a few more files with the same filename but different extension, namely ".c", ".exp", ".lib", ".obj" and ".pyd.manifest"

It seems like the project is still working and the performance remains on Cython level even I moved those files away (".c" ".exp", ".lib", ".obj" and ".pyd.manifest")
I am confused with those output files from the compiler, not sure what's necessary and what's not, and how shall I use them and treat them.

My setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize("myCythonFile.pyx",)
)
```

Comment: This is explained in the Cython docs, but these are all intermediate files generated by the Cython and C compilers. If you get rid of them, the module will still work, but it may take longer to rebuild if you change something, and you may not have any C-level debug information available if you need to debug things, and you may not be able to build any other modules that need to share code with this one. If you don't care about any of that, it's not a problem. If you want to understand better, you need to read the docs, then ask a more specific question about whatever part(s) you don't get.

Comment: Meanwhile, your second question is a completely different question, so ask it separately.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed the second question just to be clear

Comment: Normally I only deploy the pyc files after UAT.
Regarding your "debug things", if i want to keep the similar level of traceback, shall I also deploy the files under the build/tmp.win32-2.7/Release?

Comment: If so, how shall I deploy in terms of the hierarchy of those directories?

Comment: Are you deploying things manually? That's usually not a good idea. Much better to use `setuptools` to build a wheel, or virtualenv tools to create a portable environment, etc. You should't have to copy things into a Release directory.

Answer (score 1):

All of these files are temporary files.

Cython compiles each of your `pyx` files (you only have one) to C code in matching `.c` files. It can also emit other files, like an HTML file to make the C code more readable, but by default, this is all it gives you, and you didn't ask for anything extra.

Cython then asks whatever C compiler you have configured via `distutils`—in your case, that's MSVC (Microsoft Visual C++, the C and C++ compiler that comes with Visual Studio)—and to build a `.dll`/`.pyd` file out of those `.c` files. The full details of what files that creates and what they mean depend on your compiler version, but basically it creates a `.obj` file for each `.c` file, then a `.lib` import library and `.exp` export library to go with your `.dll`, and a `.manifest` file that allows loading the library as an assembly.

Some of these files—in particular the `.c` and `.obj` files—are very handy for debugging if something goes wrong in the compiled code. (Cython-generated C code can be pretty ugly to trace through, but raw machine code can be even worse.)

All of these files can help make rebuilds after minor changes faster.

Some of these files are also needed if you want to do more complicated things like linking other libraries against your library.

If you're not doing any of those things, you don't need them. But there's also really no reason to get rid of them. (If you want to redistribute your code, you're probably going to build a source package, and a binary wheel, and both of those know how to skip over unnecessary intermediate files.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have a lot better understanding now!